# Chrome Devtools CSS-Mediaqueries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

I map served resources to my filesystem using DevTools(<kbd>F12</kbd>). Unfortunately mediaqueries seems to have no mapping after browser restart. As a workaround i remap the sources like this:

In the *sources*-tab i must:

1. "Remove folder from workspace"
2. "Add folder to workspace"
3. Grant access to Filesystem.
4. Map the Resource again.

Is this a bug or do i misunderstanding a feature?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Could you please file it on crbug.com/new with details, so that developer tools team would be able to reproduce it?